# Windows Server 2008 extremely limited user

Tags: windows-server-2008, user-management

I have a couple AWS windows 2008 instances that are about to go into production but I need them to be load tested first. We found an overseas group to do the load testing but they want to be able to monitor the CPU usage while they run their tests. My first thought was to create an extremely limited user account that could RDP into the server and run Performance Monitor. However I can't figure out how to limit a user in that way. I'm not a server guy, I'm mostly a developer. I've scoured Google and read through the only Windows Server book we have in the office but can't find they answer. Any help and/or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to grant the user(s) the "Profile system performance" user right in the Local Security Policy of the server, accessed via the Security Configuration Management applet in Administrative Tools.

Comment: That works for granting that right, but how would I go about limiting everything else?

Comment: "everything else" is a pretty broad canvas. Exactly what do you want to restrict? Have you tried logging on as a standard user and see what actions are available to the standard user?

Comment: That's a valid point, I logged in and it seems restricted enough. I just don't understand why user rights and groups are so abstracted.